# ELMAH is not filtering exception messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, elmah

I have the current regular expression filters set up in my web.config file for ELMAH

```
      <test>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="PortalMasterPage is redirecting to filename/default.aspx"/>
      </test>
      <test>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="^Request for principal permission failed.$"/>
      </test>
      <test>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="^The file '.*\.aspx' does not exist\.$"/>
      </test>
      <test>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="^This is an invalid webresource request\.$"/>
      </test>
      <test>
        <regex binding="Exception.Message" pattern="^This is an invalid script resource request\.$"/>
      </test>
```

...but ELMAH seems to ignore these completely. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It has come to my attention that regular expressions differ slightly from language to language, so maybe .NET's regex engine isn't matching these properly?

Comment: `​​​ \b` may not be what you want.

Comment: @SLaks, I've removed those tests from the question, as they are less problematic than the ones now remaining. thanks!